# Making a column of buttons in the fragment's layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button, overlapping

So, I'm trying to make a column of buttons. After googling for a solution, the best I can find is to place it into a LinearLayout or something of the kind, but my problem is that I'm using fragments (specifically navigation type "Tabs + Swipe") and it doesn't use a layout as far as I can see. (well, OK, it does, but not on the pageviewer) To get a single button I modified the generated code to look like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        final TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);

        final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setText("Btn Text"); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // Perform action on click
            }
        });
```

After consulting the guys over at Reddit/LearnProgramming I was informed instead of making an XML for every button that I should programmatically make the buttons and change the layout Params. i was a bit confused and lost their help, so I went back to google.
After that, my code now looks like:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
            final Button newButton = new Button(getActivity());
            newButton.setText("This is some text for"+i);
            newButton.setTag(i);
            arrList.add(newButton);
           // ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(newButton); // Works for a single button

            ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(newButton, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  newButton.setText("I changed it.");
              }
          });
            }

        return rootView;
    }
```

What this results in is a default textview number stating what page I'm on and four buttons that overlap. I know it overlaps and that they are all being displayed because I can see the numbers, 1-4 overlapped. I'm not new to programming, but I am fairly new to android programming.

What I would LIKE to happen is for the buttons to be added beneath each other, in a row.
Can anyone push me in the right direction? I made this as clear as possible, but if you need any more information I would be happy to add it.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here's the fragment_main_dummy.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So it is relative, but I don't see a reference to RelativeLayout anywhere in the code, so I was lead to believe that it wasn't being used?
Also, I tried adding a LinearLayout as a child in the xml, but I haven't done anything with it.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't mention what is the layout where the `Buttons` are being added. If the `rootView` is a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` it's normal the buttons overlap as you didn't make special `LayoutParams`.

Comment: I don't think there is one. This is just the code from the default eclipse project with "Tabs + Swipe".

Comment: Well, can you look and see how does the `fragment_main_dummy.xml` file looks like? Is the root tag a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`(or you could just post it in the question)

Comment: I added to it. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
   final Button newButton = new Button(getActivity());
   newButton.setText("This is some text for"+i);
   newButton.setTag(i);
   arrList.add(newButton);
   newButton.setId(1000 + i);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
   rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i == 0 ? R.id.MyLayout : newButton.getId() - 1);
   newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             newButton.setText("I changed it.");
        }
   });
   ((RelativeLayout) rootView).addView(newButton, rlp);
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. It works. Thanks.
So I didn't do anything wrong, I just never gave it a rule to position it beneath the previous view?

I have the tags to keep track of which I've clicked, now I should be able to use either the tag or the ID to keep track of which button I press in the arraylist, right?

Comment: @Vasir Yes `RelativeLayout` requires its children to have placement rules specified on them otherwise they'll end up on the top left corner one in top of the other. You could use the id or the tag, I would use ids as I consider it to be cleaner.